# Replace missing value without knowing exact position in AWK

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to process a [GTF/GFF](https://m.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/gff.html) file which I download from ensemble. The truncated version of the file looks like this:

```
1   ensembl gene    5273    10061   .   -   .   gene_id ENSGALG00000054818; gene_version 1; gene_source ensembl; gene_biotype protein_coding;
1   ensembl transcript  5273    10061   .   -   .   gene_id ENSGALG00000054818; gene_version 1; transcript_id ENSGALT00000098984; transcript_version 1; gene_source ensembl; gene_biotype protein_coding; transcript_source ensembl; transcript_biotype protein_coding;
1   ensembl gene    58427   58617   .   +   .   gene_id ENSGALG00000047594; gene_version 1; gene_name RF00004; gene_source ensembl; gene_biotype snRNA;
1   ensembl transcript  58427   58617   .   +   .   gene_id ENSGALG00000047594; gene_version 1; transcript_id ENSGALT00000094382; transcript_version 1; gene_name RF00004; gene_source ensembl; gene_biotype snRNA; transcript_name RF00004-201; transcript_source ensembl; transcript_biotype snRNA;
1   ensembl exon    58427   58617   .   +   .   gene_id ENSGALG00000047594; gene_version 1; transcript_id ENSGALT00000094382; transcript_version 1; exon_number 1; gene_name RF00004; gene_source ensembl; gene_biotype snRNA; transcript_name RF00004-201; transcript_source ensembl; transcript_biotype snRNA; exon_id ENSGALE00000460125; exon_version 1;
1   ensembl gene    63264   63454   .   +   .   gene_id ENSGALG00000049206; gene_version 1; gene_name RF00004; gene_source ensembl; gene_biotype snRNA;
1   ensembl transcript  63264   63454   .   +   .   gene_id ENSGALG00000049206; gene_version 1; transcript_id ENSGALT00000092780; transcript_version 1; gene_name RF00004; gene_source ensembl; gene_biotype snRNA; transcript_name RF00004-201; transcript_source ensembl; transcript_biotype snRNA;
1   ensembl exon    63264   63454   .   +   .   gene_id ENSGALG00000049206; gene_version 1; transcript_id ENSGALT00000092780; transcript_version 1; exon_number 1; gene_name RF00004; gene_source ensembl; gene_biotype snRNA; transcript_name RF00004-201; transcript_source ensembl; transcript_biotype snRNA; exon_id ENSGALE00000501941; exon_version 1;
```

(Nine tab separated columns.)

In some rows there are attributes missing like `gene_name`, `transcript_id` or `transcript_name`.

- If `gene_name` is missing I wanted to replace it with `gene_id`,
- and if `transcript_name` is missing I wanted to replace it with `transcript_id` (in the case of missing `transcript_id` it gets replaced by `gene_id`).

However, the information for `transcript_id` or lets better say the position of this information is unknown. How would I look for the attribute and in case it is missing, replace it with the value of `transcript_id` with unknown positional information

I achieved to replace the missing value for `gene_name` with the value for `gene_id` like this:

```
awk '{if (!/gene_name/) print $0, "gene_name " $10; else print $0}' input.gtf > output.gtf
```

This worked pretty fine but only because in this particular case I knew the position of the value that I used as a replacement. I could not figure out how I would achieve this when the position of the match is unknown.

I used the following code to get unknown position information but could not integrate a check for the missmatch like in the first example above:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if ($i ~ "transcript_name") print$0,"transcript_name ", $(i+1) } }' input.gtf > output.gtf
```

The condition is that only if `transcript_name` is not already present in the row it should be replaced by the value for `transcript_id`.

I really would appreciate some help with this!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will have a look at perl! The example that you linked is doing exactly what I wanted. However, I can not get it running there seem to be a "syntax error near unexpected token `(' " which I could not find. Do you have an idea where this error might occur?

Comment: see my answer and let me know if you're still getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an awk script;

**script.awk**:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
  gsub(/; *$/, "", $9)        # trim trailing `;'
  split($9, pairs, / *; */)   # split attributes into pairs
  for (i in pairs) {
    split(pairs[i], kv, / */) # split pair into key and value
    attr[kv[1]] = kv[2]       # add it to `attr'
  }
  # fill missing fields
  if (!("gene_name" in attr))
    attr["gene_name"] = attr["gene_id"]
  if (!("transcript_id" in attr))
    attr["transcript_id"] = attr["gene_id"]
  if (!("transcript_name" in attr))
    attr["transcript_name"] = attr["transcript_id"];
  # recreate the attributes field
  attr_all = sep = ""
  for (k in attr) {
    attr_all = attr_all sep k " " attr[k]
    sep = "; "
  }
  # update the record with new attributes
  $9 = attr_all 
}
1 # print record
```

Usage example:

```sh
awk -f script.awk inputfile
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/vDFpqk).

Comment: Sorry, I did not know how to use an awk script. Thanks for clarifying, that worked great!.

Comment: How would you modify the code in order to skip the header of the file (5 lines) and then start to generate the array for the attributes? I tried to modify the parameters in the beginning ``` awk -f BEGIN {FNR>5;FS=OFS="\t"} .....``` but unfortunately this was not working as expected. If the file contains a header then your code produces the attribute names but without any value.

Comment: @PhiH insert `NR>5` before `{` at 5th line of the script.

Comment: Works perfectly! I thought I had to specify this before, thanks for the quick fix!